# Which Mexican law or regulation restricts entry from the US to Mexico via the land border?

Tags: legal, covid-19, borders, mexico, overland

Traveling **from** Mexico to the US is restricted by [this notification](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2021/08/23/2021-18061/notification-of-temporary-travel-restrictions-applicable-to-land-ports-of-entry-and-ferries-service) issued by the DHS and continually extended every month. However I can't seem to find an exact law restriction land border travel **to** Mexico from the US. The [Mexican consulate in the US](https://mx.usembassy.gov/travel-restrictions-fact-sheet/) merely re-iterates the US version of the restriction, even if you [switch to the Spanish version](https://mx.usembassy.gov/es/hoja-informativas-restricciones-de-viaje/) of their website. Every [other website](https://www.elheraldodejuarez.com.mx/local/se-extienden-las-restricciones-para-cruzar-a-los-estados-unidos-5251459.html) that I can find likewise merely refers to the US regulations, not the Mexican regulations. I can also [find news](https://thehill.com/homenews/state-watch/505806-mexico-closes-border-in-arizona-as-coronavirus-cases-in-both-country) of the Mexican state of Sonora closing the border in July 2020 but this seems like a temporary regulation that only applied to one state.

Hence... does this law or regulation actually exist on the Mexican side? In *practice* the land border [is definitely open](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159550/is-the-us-mexico-land-border-open-for-non-essential-travels-traveler-has-a-fr/168649#168649) but I prefer to follow all rules and regulations, so I won't be driving into Mexico unless I'm certain that its legal to do so. Going back to the US won't be a problem as I fall under one of the exceptions so I just need to make sure I won't be in violation of any Mexican regulations.

Comment: [This article](https://www.mexperience.com/mexico-land-border-restrictions-closure-covid-19/) claims that there are no restrictions. Google can't seem to find more authoritative sources than that, unfortunately.

Comment: @Kevin yep looks like there’s no such law but I’ll wait a couple of days before adding this as an answer. What’s weird is that US media is even talking about a “closed” border even though in reality the closure has zero effect whatsoever on US citizens and green card holders.

Comment: @JonathanReez The "closed" border has 100% effect on non US citizens.  I live near Tijuana and have not been able to cross since March 2020.  I know some that cross both ways several times a week, just to go shopping or to visit friends etc., and others (like my family) can't even collect our mail.

Comment: A friend was detained at the border for over 2 hours while trying to cross with a tourist visa - she had an intl flight from LAX that day, so thought that would be considered "essential travel", however CBP didn't see it that way.  Eventually they let her cross, but said it wouldn't happen again.

Comment: @Midavalo correct but US media made me seriously believe that I can’t legally drive to Mexico, rather than saying “US government bans foreign citizens from land border, but citizens are not affected in the slightest”. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm just frustrated by the inconsistency. I can't drive into the US (I'm only 20 mins from the Port of entry), but I could fly to San Diego if I want to spend the money. There is a charter company that flies people from Ensenada to San Diego for about $250 - people who would be denied entry at the land crossing!

Comment: @Midavalo agreed and I wish countries stopped playing the pandemic travel closures game already. All these bans don’t work anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you will find a law that says the border is closed or restricted, simply because it's not.  The border from the US to Mexico (at least for the land crossings from San Diego, CA to Tijuana, BC) is wide open.  Anyone (not just US citizens) is able to cross *into* Mexico on foot or by vehicle.  The only restrictions here are on crossing from Mexico into the US (US citizens, green card holders, and work or study visa holders are exempt from these restrictions).

There have occasionally been restrictions from Calexico, CA to Mexicali, BC, but this is infrequent and usually only for Mexican or US holidays.  The fact that INM announces when they will be restricting entry at Mexicali, and that they allow you to enter upon showing passport (when crossing on foot) would suggest that legally the crossings into Mexico are open.

This year the Mexican government have frequently stated that they believe the border should be open, and they have been working hard to convince the US government to ease or remove restrictions.